# Concourse resource to manage custom snapshot versions

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-git-resource, concourse-task, concourse-resource-types

I have a concourse pipeline which takes multiple branches as input.
Say `branch1`, `branch2`, `branch3` etc.
When branch1 is pinned from ui and built it generated `branch1-snapshot`. On pinning branch2 it generates `branch2-snapshot` and so on.
It works fine.

Now I would like to save all the snapshot names in a repo or a in a file in a repo, so that whenever there is a need to deploy a particular snapshot version generated by my multibranch job, all i have to do is list out the versions available in this file/repo and give user the option to pin one version and hit the deploy button.

Is there a concourse resource which fulfills this.

Note: `semver` wont satisfy my requirement as the version will not be in a semantic versioning format.